# the_title() displays first post title instead of page title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've seen I'm not the first one for asking that question, but none of the solutions I've found worked for me.
I am developing an online store, which has different pages for the different product categories. each category has his own page. and I have a template file which refers to that type of page. each page title is the category name. 
this is the code in my template file:

```
<div id="store-front" class="main-music-area">
  <?php if ( $products->have_posts() ) : $i = 1; ?>

      <header class="page-header">
         <?php
          the_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
         ?>
      </header><!-- .page-header -->
```

It worked just fine until now, but now what I am getting is the first post title, instead of the page/category title, and I can't find the reason why. any suggestions? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using have_posts which steps into "the loop" so the_title is relates to the products loop rather the page.

So, you can use `get_the_title()` and use the page's ID or to first display the title and only then use the `have_posts` function.

For example:

```
  <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
  <header class="page-header">
     <?php
      the_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
     ?>
  </header><!-- .page-header -->
  <?php if ( $products->have_posts() ) : $i = 1; ?>
```

Edit: You've probably started a loop prior to this part, so before calling the_title() use rewind_posts() in order to reset the previous loop.

[**the_title()**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

> Displays or returns the unescaped title of the current post. This tag
>   may only be used within The Loop, to get the title of a post outside
>   of the loop use get_the_title. If the post is protected or private,
>   this will be noted by the words "Protected: " or "Private: " prepended
>   to the title.

[**have_posts**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts)

> **As a side effect, have_posts starts, steps through**, or resets The
>   Loop. At the end of the loop, have_posts returns 0 after calling
>   rewind_posts.

Comment: hey Ofir. I have tried to first display the title, and only then the 'have_post', but the result was the same. if i use 'get_the_title()', as i use the same template file for varius of pages, I can't write the page ID. is there a way I can call the current page ID?

Comment: prior to calling the_title() use rewind_posts(); I believe that you're starting a loop prior to this part. have updated the answer.

Comment: Right at the beginning of your code, place the function `the_post();` and then get the current page id like `$page_id = get_the_ID();`. Then when echoing the page title, do it like `echo get_the_title($page_id);`. If that does not work, recheck your query. It shouldn't behave this way.

Comment: @yoD If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I actually found that using `single_post_title()` gave the correct response, as `wp_title()` also included the site description.